# How to get HtmlDocument using CefSharp?

Tags: dom, cefsharp

No way to get html element like ie WebBrowser?WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById(string id);
I am a new user of CefSharp,thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('element_Id');");
```

Comment: actually thats the only easy work around to work with dom elements in `CefSharp` or other one you can use is `ChromeDriver`